# Cohomology of permutation representation

Tags: representation-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Consider the action of $S_n$ over $\{1,...,n\}$ consider the associated representation with integral coefficients $X_n$. What are $H^r(S_n,X_n)$?

More in general is there a nice way to predict the cohomology groups of a permutational representation in terms of the action?

Comment: By Shapiro's Lemma, $H^r(S_n,X_n)\cong H^r(S_{n-1},\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Oh Yes! thanks. Is it easy then to compute the latter cohomology groups?

Comment: It's not easy, but they're known, and there's an extensive literature. Try Googling "integral cohomology of symmetric groups"